# 32 bit libc with debug symbols on x64

Tags: c, assembly, ubuntu-12.04

I am searching how to install 32 bit non-stripped libc on a x64 system. I have already lib32 libc installed but it is stripped, I have libc-2.15.so on my Ubuntu 12.04 x64. Does anyone know the name of the package I need, because I thinks libc6-dbg only have x64 versions.

Answer (score 1):

On systems that are Multi-Arch capable, you will need to enable it (`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`), then install the `libc6-dbg:i386` package. This may remove half of your system though, if there is something in the dependency chain that is not yet Multi-Archified.

I find biarch (or triarch) development extremely error-prone myself and strongly advice to use a 32-bit chroot (e.g. with `linux32 cowbuilder --bindmounts "$HOME" --login` or using the `schroot` utility) instead.